# How should I combine grain and hot water when doughing in

Tags: mash, all-grain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the grain or strike water be added to the mash tun first?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/should-the-grain-or-strike-water-be-added-to-the-mash-tun-first)

Should I add water first, then grain? Grain, then water? Both at the same time?

I'm worried that adding grain to hot water might expose some of the grain to too high a temperature. On the other hand, adding water to grain seems like it would cause dough-balls. Combining both at once seems like you'd need at least 3 hands!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Should the grain or strike water be added to the mash tun first?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/should-the-grain-or-strike-water-be-added-to-the-mash-tun-first)